# How to match heterogeneous sequences of whitespace characters?

Tags: python, regex

For example: `"\t\t \v"` and `"      \f"` should match. `"\t\t\t"`, `"    "` and `"\f\f\f"` should not match.

So basically, I would like to exclude the first captured character, something similar to this `(\s)\1*[^\S\1]+\s*`. But this won't work since we cannot put captured group in the `[^]`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `(\s)\1*(?!\1)\s+`?

Comment: Was about to suggest a _negative lookahead assertion_ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I got your requirement correctly, but you can try with a negative Lookahead:

```
(\s)\1*(?!\1)\s+
```

Does something like this work for you?

---

Here's a Python example:

```
regex = r"(\s)\1*(?!\1)\s+"
inputs = ["\t\t \v", "\f", "\t\t\t", " ", "\f\f\f", "\f \f"]

for s in inputs:
    if re.match(regex, s):
        print "Found a match."
    else:
        print ("No matches!")
```

**Output:**

```
Found a match.
No matches!
No matches!
No matches!
No matches!
Found a match.
```

I'm not sure why you expect `\f` to be a match if  is not. If that wasn't a mistake, can you please clarify?

Comment: I think this is display problem, I actually put multiple ` ` in there. But it only display that way. " \f" is a space + `\f`, which should match. "      " is several spaces.

Comment: This is nice. Always forgot that the lookahead does not consume characters.